# Ruby - Centering a multi-line string

Tags: ruby, string, newline, quotes, centering

In Ruby, I would like to center a multi-line string so it shows up in the middle of the screen. I have looked up the Class:String Ruby documentation and also searched Google but couldn't come up with a solution.

Here's what I have tried. Here I am using the escape character \n for newline after every line so I don't have to type puts and then quotation marks on every line. I also enter the String class's center method at the end of the string, because I would like all lines to be centered, without calling the method after every line.

```
def draw_string
  puts "******** \n
        ******** \n
        ******** \n
        ********".center(150)
end
```

When I call draw_string this is what I'd like to see

```
                                   ********
                                   ********
                                   ********
                                   ********
```

This is what I get

```
                                   ******** 
******** 
******** 
********
```

Please don't ask me why I want to center this, but do give advice. It is very much appreciated

Comment: You're putting two `\n`'s between each line, not sure if that's intentional.

Comment: Looks like that was a mistake on my part. I will edit my post to have only 1 new line. I out-thought myself.

Comment: You also need to remove the extra `\n` from the string itself. It's not necessary, you are inserting a literal newline character in additional to an escaped `\n` newline. See my answer; I've removed the extra `\n`'s from the string.

Comment: If you have more than one string to center, you might write the method with the string as a parameter; i.e., `def draw_string(str)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to center each line individually. Ruby's string class does not support centering a multi-line string.

Use a simple split/map/join combination:

```
def draw_string
  puts "********
        ********
        ********
        ********".lines.map { |line| line.strip.center(150) }.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: Many thanks, it worked. Your advice is greatly appreciated. Once again, thank you